# Anaconda spyder "No existe un interprete de IPython para ejecutar..."

Tags: python, anaconda, ipython

Cuando intento ejecutar mi programa *.py* en Anaconda-spyder me sale un pop-up con el siguiente error:

> *"No existe un interprete de IPython para ejecutar nombre_del_programa.py Por favorabra uno nuevo e intente otra vez"*

Carezco de permisos de administrador en el ordenador actual.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Interpreto que tienes puesto Anaconda ¿Has probado [`Anaconda Navigator`](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/)?¿Has mirado cómo se usa `conda`? Anaconda no necesita privilegios de administrador.

Comment: ¿jaureg puedes abrir una terminal IPython si vas al menú `Ver` -> `Paneles` -> `Terminal de IPython`? Por defecto Spyder ejecuta el script usando la consola IPython activa en ese momento, si no tienes ninguna abierta no inicia una, te muestra la advertencia que comentas.

Comment: Se te debe haber cerrado el terminal de Python en Spyder. Puedes reabrirlo con CTRL+T o yendo a Terminales-> Abrir una terminal de Python

Answer (score 1):

lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

- desinstale y reinstale Spyder Anaconda aún me daba el error
- luego cerré todas las ventanas con excepción del editor del código
- por último presione el botón ejecutar de nuevo el mismo archivo (f6) y puede compilar

Answer (score -1):

En el toolbar de spyder hay una pestaña llamada "Consoles", ahi está la opción de Abrir una consola IPython. El atajo es Ctrl + T.